# tabBar & navigation bar became dark after updating to Xcode 8

Tags: ios, uinavigationbar, uitabbar, swift3, xcode8

After updating my Xcode to Xcode 8, i'm facing this strange issue. I have a tab bar and 3 tabs in it when tab1 is selected tab bar and navigation looks like this :

tab bar's background color is white but its showing a dark color instead

[image]

and when I select any other tab  the problems gets fix

in the below image I've selected tab2

[image]

I do not know why its happening but in tab1's ViewController I have a tableView and in tab2 I have a ViewController

anybody knows why is this happening ??

debug hierarchy :

when TAB1 is selected 
[image]

---

when any other tab is selected 
[image]

i dont know why but tabbar's  UIVisualEffectBackdropView's background color is black on tab1 and its transparent in 
other tabs

Comment: This looks like you have another view or mask on top of it. Not only background is different, the tab image colour appears to be different as well. Or check some alpha-s. If you have set some alpha, the previous iOS SDK could have not understood it before.

Comment: Please see the answer below. Hope this is already fixed for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

turn out adding shadow on my toolBar caused the issue :

the below code was giving me proper shadow in Xcode7 (swift 2) but after updating to Xcode 8 (swift 3) it changed the color of my other bars (tab bar + navigation bar) :

```
toolbar.layer.masksToBounds = false
toolbar.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: -1, height: 1)
toolbar.layer.shadowRadius = 1
toolbar.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.5
```

Answer (score 14):

For anyone else suffering this problem for different reasons to OP:

This exact problem occurred for me when I added the line `edgesForExtendedLayout = []` into my UIViewController's `loadView()` method to [stop my view going under the navigation bar](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/example-code/uikit/how-to-stop-your-view-going-under-the-navigation-bar-using-edgesforextendedlayout). Thus, removing that line and instead achieving the same aim using `navigationController?.navigationBar.isTranslucent = false` fixed it for me (although John Doe's solution may have been viable too). I guess that when there is no view laid under your toolbar, the `UIVisualEffectBackdropView` becomes opaque and it just happens to be black. This appears to produce a dark toolbar if your toolbar is transparent.

Comment: This is the best answer ever!. Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

You can solve this locally (for e.g. if you have a CustomTabBarController), and globally. I am providing both solutions here, just for you:

**1. Locally:**

```
    class YourCustomTabBarVC: UITabBarController {

    //MARK:- Initializers
    required init?(coder aDecoder:NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        __customInit()
    }  

    override init(nibName nibNameOrNil: String?, bundle nibBundleOrNil: Bundle?) {
        super.init(nibName: nibNameOrNil, bundle: nibBundleOrNil)
        __customInit()
    }

    fileprivate func __customInit() {
        addObservers()

       //Customize TabBar appearance:
        tabBar.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
    }
    }
```

**2. Globally: in your AppDelegate.swift:**

```
 func application(_ application: UIApplication,
                 didFinishLaunchingWithOptions
    launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
   /* Your other code*/   
   UITabBar.appearance().backgroundColor = UIColor.white // {UR_DESIRED_COLOR}

}
```

I would suggest you to use the global method. Add that one line, and voila! You will be scrambling to write a personal thank you message right underneath here!

Answer (score 0):

This helped me while performing segue:

Remove `hidesBottomBarWhenPushed` or disable it.

```swift
destination.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = false
```

Answer (score 0):

I have just changed view controller's `background color` property from **.default** to **.systemBackgroundColor**